# Cannot retrieve object from IgniteCach, throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, ignite

I am trying to add Ignite to an existing apache-tomcat application and I am running into an issue trying to retrieve data that I have previously inserted into an IgniteCache.

Below is a mockup of the code in question.

```
public static MyClass getInstance(){
    Ignite ig = WSUtil.getIgnite();
    IgniteCache<Integer,MyClass> myCache = ig.getOrCreateCache("MyClass");
    MyClass instance = myCache.get( 0 );
    if(instance == null) {
        try{
            instance =  //IO opperations to create instance 
            myCache.put(0, instance);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("\tMessage: "+e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }finally {
            //close IO
        }
        
    }
    return instance; 
}
```

The first time this method is called an instance variable is successful created and stored but the second time it is called, the following errors occur when `myCache.get( 0 )` is called :

```
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.xxxx.services.MyClass
        at com.xxxx.services.misc.impl.yyyy.getInstance(yyyy.java:84)
        at com.xxxx.services.misc.impl.zzzz.getProductName(zzzz.java:324)
        at com.xxxx.services.misc.impl.cccc.getProductName(cccc.java:92)
        at com.xxxx.services.misc.impl.cccc.getProductInfo(cccc.java:752)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at com.xxxx.prime.aop.MethodCachingInterceptor.invoke(MethodCachingInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.getProductInfo(Unknown Source)
        at com.xxxx.ws.ProductInfoWS.invoke(ProductInfoWS.java:60)
        at com.xxxx.ws.ProductInfoWS.invoke(ProductInfoWS.java:25)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invokeProvider(InstanceResolver.java:256)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invokeProvider(InvokerTube.java:156)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.provider.SyncProviderInvokerTube.processRequest(SyncProviderInvokerTube.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doGet(WSServlet.java:82)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.xxxx.services.MyClass
        ... 60 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: com.xxxx.services.MyClass
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxxx.services.MyClass
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        ... 29 more
```

I have tried to so something similar with a simple Person object running an Ignite server on my workstation without any problem.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IgniteException{
        //preparing igniteconfig
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setClientMode(true);
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
        
        IgniteCache <Integer, Person> personCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("personCache");
        Person p = new Person("Billy","Jean");
        personCache.put(0, p);
        
        Person p2 = personCache.get(0);
        
        System.out.println("p: " + p.toString());
        System.out.println("p2: " + p2.toString());
        
        System.out.println(">> task exectued, check output");
        ignite.close();
}
```

Comment: What does `Class.forName("com.MyClass")` yield if added before `get(0)` line?

Comment: In the debugger I can see that evaluated to: `Class<T> (com.MyClass)`, with the toString evaluating to `class com.MyClass`

Comment: After more reading I have made sure that peer class loading is turned on on both the client and server (it was).  Despite this I also added the compiled jars containing MyClass to ii/apache-ignite-2.9.1-bin/libs but still get errors when trying to pull the value out from the cache.

Comment: Peer class loading will not peer load key-value classes. Please provide complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @alamar Edited post to include full sanitized stack trace.

Comment: I ran a remote task and some client side code to see the class loader associated with Ignite vs Custom classes.  This is what I got on the server:  "org.apache.ignite.Ignite"
    Class associated with ClassLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
    "com.xxxx.services.MyClass"
    Class associated with ClassLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
And on the client:
 "org.apache.ignite.Ignite"
 Class associated with ClassLoader = org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader
 "com.xxxx.services.MyClass"
 Class associated with ClassLoader = java.net.URLClassLoader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that Ignite and your code are loaded from two different classloaders (as you have pointed out), such as, Apache Ignite may be loaded from the common libraries directory while the user code may be loaded from a specific web app directory. In this case, Apache Ignite may not see your libraries.

You can try setting `IgniteConfiguration.classLoader` property to e.g. `getClass().getClassLoader()` before starting Ignite node.

Comment: Thank you so much, for anyone that stumbles on this this is the exact syntax I added: cfg.setClassLoader(MyClass.class.getClassLoader());